# XMLBeans dates without timezone information

Tags: java, xml, datetime, xsd, xmlbeans

This question is related to:
[XmlBeans XmlDateTime format without timezone info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468299/xmlbeans-xmldatetime-format-without-timezone-info)

But I need to print a date in XMLBeans without any timezone info.
What I read from World Wide Web consortium is:

> A "date object" is an object with year, month, and day properties just
>   like those of dateTime objects, plus an **optional** timezone-valued
>   timezone property

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date

The key word is **optional**. I need to remove it from default XMLBeans behaviour.

What I have tried:

```
XmlDateTime xmlDateTime = XmlDateTime.Factory.newInstance();
xmlDateTime.setCalendarValue(new GregorianCalendar());
GDateBuilder gdb = new GDateBuilder(xmlDateTime.getDateValue());
gdb.normalize();
xmlDateTime.setGDateValue(gdb.toGDate());
instruction.setReqdExctnDt(gdb.getCalendar());
CBIPartyIdentification4 partyId = CBIPartyIdentification4.Factory.newInstance();
```

What I get is `2014-05-16Z` what I need is `2014-05-16`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the class XmlCalendar, which won't add time zone information:

```
XmlDateTime xmlDateTime = XmlDateTime.Factory.newInstance();
Calendar xmlCalendar = new XmlCalendar();
xmlCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
xmlCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
xmlCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 22);
xmlDateTime.setCalendarValue(xmlCalendar);
```